# Angular 2 - Change detection issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using `Angular 2.1.1` for my application.

**Scenario**
Consider two components which interact with each other.
`DeviceSettingsComponent` is active and visible to the user. It has the a close button like:

```
<a class="close" (click)="closeDeviceSettings()">&times;</a>
```

The button handler method basically just emits an event:

```
private closeDeviceSettings(): void {
    this.sharedService.broadcast('deviceSettingsClosed');
}
```

`MainComponent` is listening to that event:

```
this.sharedService.on('deviceSettingsClosed', () => this.isDeviceSettingsOpen = false);
```

From `MainComponent` template:

```
<div class="main-device-settings" *ngIf="isDeviceSettingsOpen">
    <device-settings [device]="openSettingsData.device"></device-settings>
</div>
```

This works fine in `Angular 2.1.1`.

**Problem**
When I update to `Angular 2.2.x` there is a 3-5 sec delay between clicking on the close button and the `DeviceSettingsComponent` being destroyed / removed from DOM. No code (besides Angular version in package.json) changed.
I can tell that it is not a problem with the event, the `isDeviceSettingsOpen` property in `MainComponent` is immediately updated when clicking the close button. It seems to me like the change detection is somehow delayed.

**Someone has a clue what is going on?**

## Update

I managed to fix it by manually invoke a change detection right after updating my property like this:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.on('deviceSettingsClosed', () => {
        this.isDeviceSettingsOpen = false
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
}
```

The component is now immediatly removed from DOM. But I don't like this solution and don't understand why it is necessary...

Comment: does it update faster if you click on the page(click anywhere in you page) immediately after you click on your button?

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: ahh, I thought it was an issue with the change detection strategy, but that confirmed it isn't. I couldn't replicate this issue in my project, are you using Subscription and Observable in your shared service?

Comment: yes I use both. But I verified that the event is immediately received and the `isDeviceSettingsOpen` property updated (using some console.logs)

Comment: after `this.isDeviceSettingsOpen = false` is executed, there is a delay of few seconds until the component is actually destroyed

Comment: im trying to replicate this error with a basic setup of angular 2.2.1, no luck yet. 

Comment: maybe I should add that this is an Angular hybrid app (ng1 as base and ng2 components etc. donwgraded using `UpgradeAdapter`), no idea if this makes a difference with the problem.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to diagnose the issue if the problem could be reproduced. I suggest you create a project which presents this issue, host it online somewhere and share it here.

Comment: Check the example I provided in the comments to my answer, it creates a similar situation, at least as I understand it... [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZoIaqgECJStuQkPstFZy?p=preview)

Comment: **Updated** my question.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar issue with a colleague's project. The problem there was heavy logic on the template of the component (parsing dates from strings in a table).

Clicking the button triggered a refresh of the view and parsing again all the dates.

Try removing the contents of the click handler of the button and see if there is still a delay of 3-5 seconds after you click the button until the page is responsive again. If so, it means the problem isn't with the handler.

See if you have complicated logic on the view (the component template).

The solution in this case, if it is the cause of your problem, is moving the problematic logic to the component itself and using the product of the calculations in the view.

Comment: From his comment "yes I use both. But I verified that the event is immediately received and the isDeviceSettingsOpen property updated (using some console.logs)", if that is correct, then there should be no issues with the "logic".

Comment: @borislemke I use "logic" as a shorthand for business logic. As I wrote, the problem could be unrelated to the button itself or the action it performs. For instance, if the OP has a huge table which gets its row data from CSV values and the splitting of the CSV is done on the view, each click on the button could cause the entire process of building the table to run again. This logic could be the problematic one, not the one that is bound to the button.

Comment: Yes I understand. But he says, from the moment that the variable has cahanged to false, and the button actually gets removed takes 2 - 5seconds. There is no "logic" in between these 2 events.

Comment: 1. His "logic." -> 2. isDeviceSettingsOpen = false -> 3. Button is removed from DOM. You see, there is no user "logic" in between step 2 and 3.

Comment: @borislemke That is correct, there is no "logic" really involved here which could cause this. I guess it might be related to Angular's change detection...

Comment: Seems a demo is in order... Open [this JSFiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZoIaqgECJStuQkPstFZy?p=preview). You can see that it takes a long time to load and every click on the Test button takes a long time to finish, even though the only code that the button executes is a print to the log.

Comment: The reason for this is that the view runs the very heavy calc() function three times. Each time the Test button is clicked, this happens again. Like I said in my previous answers, the heavy logic doesn't have to be bound to the button itself but it can be run by the view and cause this issue.

Comment: When the button is clicked, angular builds the entire template anew and so it has to run the three functions again. It's part of the change detection mechanism.

Comment: I understand what you mean but that is not the problem. I could fix it but don't undestand why... (see my **Update** in the question)

Comment: Is the issue still ongoing? If so, what is the change detection strategy of the components?